# vb.net to c#.net mongodb sort by date

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

I'm trying to get a small snippet of code from vb.net to c#.net using mongoDB driver working. It's almost working, but I can't seem to get the doc out of the mongoCursor in the same way I do from vb.net.

vb.net code:

```
        Dim latest = updateCollection.FindAll.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("date")).SetLimit(1)
        Dim latestDoc As BsonDocument = latest(0)
```

c#.net code:

```
        var updateCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("updateInfo");
        var sortby = SortBy.Descending("date");
        var latest = (updateCollection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(sortby).SetLimit(1));
        var latestDoc = latest.ToBsonDocument();
```

I've tried something like

```
        var latestDoc = latest[0];
```

as well, but it hasn't worked. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Which driver version is this? I'm not finding the .FindAll() method with driver 2.0 driver. At any rate, the VB.NET and C# look equivalent except that you "latest" returns a cursor, so you'll want to get an item the cursor is positioned at, not call methods on the cursor directly hoping it will be an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a MongoCursor, not an item back from that that method, so you'll want to do something like this:

```
//add at the top of your code file
using System.Linq;


//...
//get the first result from the cursor like this:
var latestDoc = latest.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this worked. Thank you! It seems vb.net handles it differently since even though a cursor is still returned, calling latest(0) works in vb. This made me think a mongocursor is just an array or list.